# Как организовать математические операции с большим объемом данных?

Tags: php, mysql

нужен теоретический совет по работе с большим количеством данных.
В таблице сохраняется примерно от 10 до 100 тыс строк данных (от 12 до 25 колонок)
Задача состоит в том что выборке этих данных, нужно произвести определенные расчет для каждой отдельной строки и усложняется все тем, что в этих расчет участвуют средние (средние не всегда арифметические) величины по некоторым колонкам.
Сейчас при получении сразу более 10к строк получаю переполнение оперативной памяти.
Можно ли как то сделать операции расчета данных пакетно с учетом просчета средних данных одновременно ?
Для лучшего понимания:
по одному столбцу считается средние арифметическое без учета нулевых значений
по второму столбцу считается сумма всех записей умноженная на 100 (для перевода в процент)
третья колонка считается как сумма первой / сумма второй

Как это процесс можно было бы оптимизировать ?
Спасибо за любую помощь

P.S 
Стек: PHP7.1, Slim framework, Mysql 5.7, Драйвер для работы с БД Eloquent ORM

Comment: а в чем сложность расчета средних значений ? Считаете сумму и количество не нулевых значений. В конце делите сумму на количество

Comment: Стоп. Так данные у вас в таблице в БД ? Тогда в чем вообще состоит проблема. БД сама может вам посчитать все что угодно и дать нужный итоговый результат. Не надо исходные данные в программу тащить

Comment: @Mike , а в каком случае тогда производить пересчет в БД ? я имею ввиду каждый раз как только пользователь сменил какое значение нужно снова запускать пересчет всех значений ? Там просто логика такова, что если изменился столбец, который используется для расчет среднего, то нужно пересчитать все данные в таблице. И если это 50к записей, то не будет ли очень нагруженно каждый раз пересчитывать все ?

Comment: В таблице на надо хранить ни какие данные, которые могут (и тем более постоянно должны) вычисляться. Все вычисления производятся в тот момент когда эти данные понадобилось использовать

Comment: Вот ваша программа как часто делает эти расчеты и для чего ? она же наверно изредка запускается и куда то их потом отдает. Так вот задача просто вместо этой программы написать sql-запрос, который эти расчеты произведет и выдаст тот же результат

Comment: @Mike в том то и проблема что пользователь работает с данными постоянно, может часто изменять значения и их надо пересчитывать. Но в основном занимается их получение, и расчет производится каждый раз при получении отчета

Comment: Сначала надо попробовать выбрать средствами SQL нужные данные. сервер это сделает на порядок быстрее, чем с передачей всех данных к вам в программу и последующее ручное суммирование. Если и тут слишком медленно, тогда думаем о внесении избыточности в хранимые данные. Начинаем хранить суммы. Причем при обновлении пересчитывать по всей БД обычно не надо. Надо в триггере на изменение основной таблицы добавить ее значения к общим записям. (старые значения вычесть)